# What does `setupkvm` do in xv6 ? What does it really mean to "set up kernel virtual memory"?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, xv6

In `copyuvm` function `setupkvm` is called to set kernel virtual memory. Why do we need to setup kernel virtual memory when we are copying user process ? Why didn't we need that when we were doing `allocuvm` ?

Code for `copyuvm`

```cpp
// Given a parent process's page table, create a copy
// of it for a child.
pde_t*
copyuvm(pde_t *pgdir, uint sz)
{
  pde_t *d;
  pte_t *pte;
  uint pa, i, flags;
  char *mem;

  if((d = setupkvm()) == 0)
    return 0;
  for(i = 0; i < sz; i += PGSIZE){
    if((pte = walkpgdir(pgdir, (void *) i, 0)) == 0)
      panic("copyuvm: pte should exist");
    if(!(*pte & PTE_P))
      panic("copyuvm: page not present");
    pa = PTE_ADDR(*pte);
    flags = PTE_FLAGS(*pte);
    if((mem = kalloc()) == 0)
      goto bad;
    memmove(mem, (char*)P2V(pa), PGSIZE);
    if(mappages(d, (void*)i, PGSIZE, V2P(mem), flags) < 0) {
      kfree(mem);
      goto bad;
    }
  }
  return d;

bad:
  freevm(d);
  return 0;
}
```

and for `allocuvm`

```cpp
int
allocuvm(pde_t *pgdir, uint oldsz, uint newsz)
{
  char *mem;
  uint a;

  if(newsz >= KERNBASE)
    return 0;
  if(newsz < oldsz)
    return oldsz;

  a = PGROUNDUP(oldsz);
  for(; a < newsz; a += PGSIZE){
    mem = kalloc();
    if(mem == 0){
      cprintf("allocuvm out of memory\n");
      deallocuvm(pgdir, newsz, oldsz);
      return 0;
    }
    memset(mem, 0, PGSIZE);
    if(mappages(pgdir, (char*)a, PGSIZE, V2P(mem), PTE_W|PTE_U) < 0){
      cprintf("allocuvm out of memory (2)\n");
      deallocuvm(pgdir, newsz, oldsz);
      kfree(mem);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return newsz;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `copyuvm` does is that copy whole virtual memory (user + kernel) from a page directory. So during `copyuvm` we need `setupkvm` for kernel part.

On the other hand, `allocuvm` just extends existing virtual memory ( specifically heap portion). Since there already exists kernel portion of mappings in `allocuvm`, we are not bound to call `setupkvm`.